# Hard reset for SD Card interfaced with FPGA?

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, sd, reset

So I have been successfully able to interface a Sandisk SD Card with Spartan 3 FPGA (using verilog). The card after power up initializes correctly and is able to read and write data sector wise correctly. The only problem that remains is that after power up if I press the reset button the card hangs and stops working. I have also not been able to find out what a hard reset means for the SD card. Should it get reinitialized somehow? What command should I send to the card for that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: SPI or native interface ?

Comment: Should have mentioned..it is SPI interface.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to simulate your Verilog code or use analyzer to see things going on in live system.

In my opinion, there're only two circumstances when SD-card appears "hung":

- bad specification implementation, when card does not understand what is going on, or is unable to understand that previous command must be cancelled. However card must anyway tell you something other than all 1 during execution of these commands - for example during multiple block read there's CRC transmitted, which will contain zeroes, during multiple block write host must transmit CRC otherwise card responses with error, which will also contain 0s. Your task here is to check set of SD-card commands your controller uses, and adjust initialization sequence (number of spare clock cycle before you proceed to CMD0) accordingly;
- your FPGA state machine fails after you press reset. For example, clock stops working at the SD-card clock input pin, MOSI gets stuck etc. This is most suspect for hung cards, because SD-card will output nothing if clock does not toggle, or there's no activation of CS and no useful information on MOSI line.

Answer (score 0):

Once a SD card is powered and initialized but then you reset your FPGA, the code will likely start new initialization of already initialized card. The SD interface does't have any special reset line. The only **hard** reset in SD is power-on-reset, so the best way to bring a SD card into pre-initialized state is to cycle its power.

Comment: So speaking purely in terms of Verilog coding, what should I put in the `if(!reset)` portion of my code? And if the reset button is pressed what state should my designed FSM go to? Idle or CMD0?

Comment: @Candy, since after reset your FPGA likely erases all SD configuration/capacity etc. information, you need to start new fresh initialization, I guess CMD0+CS asserted (to get into SPI mode), then CMD8, CMD58, etc. in accord with initialization protocol.

Comment: I tried the CMD0+CS asserted sequence, but still the SD Card is  hung up if the reset is pressed. I am thinking to somehow get the reset and the power line of the SD Card connected so that it triggers the initial power cycle!

Comment: @Candy, I don't know how do you do SD initialization in Verilog. The protocol is awfully complex, it has so many conditions/responses to analyze. Usually a sizable MCU with hundreds and hundreds lines of C++ code is required to do this job. Which version of SD specs are you implementing? 2? 3? 4? 5+?

Comment: Yes it is complex but somehow I managed to make a customized Verilog code for it. The card is SDHC ver 2.

Comment: So what I have understood is that you can't reinitialize an SD Card that has already been initialized once. Causing it would make the SD Card go into a hung up state. You can only reinitialize the SD Card through the power-on-reset.

Comment: @Candy, not sure what do you mean by "hang". Do you have a ChipScope to debug? But I do know that if SD is set into SPI mode, only power cycling can get it back into the default SD mode.

Comment: It means the SD Card stops working and both the MOSI and the MISO lines go high!

Comment: @Candy, so if your code is doing nothing after global hardware reset, how it could be anyone fault?

Comment: In my code after hardware reset, the initialization sequence is supposed to take place but the card doesn't follow that after reset!!

Comment: @Candy, when in SPI mode, a SD card should always respond with something. Apparently your code doesn't do full analysis of responses. Again, which tools do you have to debug? Do you have traces of what you are doing, and what is the card response to each command?